# User Session (logged in)

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with SESSIONS for logged users. Website and forum are connected but when I login into website I have to login to forum again if I want to post. Session are different for website and forum.

Forum use

```
$_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;
```

And Website is using

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']) || isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {
$loggedIn = new loggedIn();
$loggedIn->db = $db;
$loggedIn->url = $CONF['url'];
$loggedIn->username = (isset($_SESSION['username'])) ? $_SESSION['username'] : $_COOKIE['username'];
$loggedIn->password = (isset($_SESSION['password'])) ? $_SESSION['password'] : $_COOKIE['password'];

$verify = $loggedIn->verify();
```

}

Also accessing via different connection methods. Website is using one php file and forum is using another php file. 
Is there any way that I can use website sessions for forum? When I login into my website and click on forum user should be logged in.

I don't know how to do this, anyone help please.

Comment: Is the forum not on your website?

Comment: It is on my website. The only problem is, when I login on my website, and click on forum, I have to login again on forum with the same login info.

Comment: On forum page put if session statement also, not only on website page

Comment: Please check question again, I've edited.